# A problem about density on metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact separable metric space and $\mu$ be a positive Radon measure on $(X,d)$. Then there exists a sequence of open subsets $(U_n)$ of $X$ such that $U_n\subseteq U_{n+1}$, $0<\mu(U_n)<\infty$ for all $n\ge 1$ and $ \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n=X$. I can not sure whether it holds or not. Any hints to help me get started would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

HINT. A Radon measure is, as part of the def'n, a locally finite measure. For each $p\in X$ let $U(p)$ be an open set containing $p,$ with $\mu(U(p))<\infty.$

A separable metric space is a Lindelof space. $\{V(p):p\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X.$